# UITest in Xcode 7: How to test keyboard layout (keyboardType)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikeyboard, ui-testing

I am currently exploring the new UITest library in Xcode, and I want to test if the keyboard that pops up upon clicking inside a `UITextView` has the proper type (in this case it should be `.PhonePad`).

I don't think this is feasible with the default `XCUIElement` and `XCUIElementAttributes` (which are still a bit blurry to me concerning their actual meaning), and I don't really understand how and what I am supposed to extend in order to be able to test this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Below code I am using for testing the Phone number and password validation check.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let tablesQuery = app.tables
tablesQuery.cells.containingType(.StaticText, identifier:"Login Using").buttons["Icon mail"].tap()
tablesQuery.textFields["Phone Number"].tap()
tablesQuery.cells.containingType(.SecureTextField, identifier:"Password").childrenMatchingType(.TextField).element.typeText("ooo")
tablesQuery.staticTexts["Login Using"].swipeUp()
tablesQuery.secureTextFields["Password"].tap()
tablesQuery.cells.containingType(.Button, identifier:"Login").childrenMatchingType(.SecureTextField).element.typeText("eeee")
tablesQuery.buttons["Login"].tap()
app.alerts["Error"].collectionViews.buttons["OK"].pressForDuration(1.1);
```

I hope this will be useful for you.